# create two pages in flutter project

Tags: flutter

I am a flutter beginner, I want to create a flutter application that contains two pages, I encounter an error that I do not understand.

Here is my code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FirstPage(),
    );
  }
}
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstPage({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _FirstPageState();
}
class _FirstPageState extends State<MyApp> {
  String bottonName = 'click';
  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    ....
    );}}
```

L'erreur est la suivante:

```
StatefulWidget.createState must return a subtype of State<FirstPage>
The createState function for FirstPage returned a state of type _FirstPageState, which is not a subtype of State<FirstPage>, violating the contract of createState.
```

Answer (score 0):

the state type of your First screen is from another widget. change it with this:

````html
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstPage({super.key});
  @override
  State<FirstPage> createState() => _FirstPageState();
}
class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  String bottonName = 'click';
  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    ....
    );}} ```
````